# Transaction across basicHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, transactions

we currently have an asmx webservice which exposes a single method to make various updates to a Sql database, wrapped internally in a SqlTransaction.

I am re-writing this service in WCF and we would like to split up the existing method into sub-calls accessed through various different WCF services.  There is a restriction to use basicHttpBinding on the services, which rules out all the built-in WCF transaction features.  Is it possible to go with this architecture and maintain a transaction across multiple service calls?  WS-TRANS has been suggested as a possible solution but I'm not familiar with it, would this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very rare that you get something for nothing. The chief difference between **basic**HttpBinding and **ws**HttpBinding is that the latter supports the **WS-*** protocols.

basicHttpBinding gives you what you had with ASMX, more or less. "transactions" would be *much* more than you had with ASMX.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know [WS-TRANS](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=trans-ws) stands for Translation Web Services so that is not going to work.

What you mean is [WS-TX](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=ws-tx) of which [WS-AtomicTransaction](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wsat/2006/06) is a part. `BasicHttpBinding` simply does not support WS-AtomicTransaction. I'm afraid that your setup is not going to work...