# WCF, long running server operations and a WinRT client

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions, windows-runtime, timeout

Here's a problem I'm currently facing:

- A WCF service exposes a large number of methods, some of which can take a longer amount of time.
- The client is a WinRT (Metro-style) application (so some .NET classes are unavailable).
- The timeout on the client has already been increased to 1.5 minutes.
- Despite the increased timeout, some operations can take longer still (but not always).
- If a timeout happens, the service continues on it's merry way. The result of the requested operation is lost. Even worse, if the operation is a success, then the client won't get the data required, and the server won't "rollback".

All operations are already implemented using the `async` pattern on the client. I could use an event-based implementation but, as far as I'm aware, the timeouts will still occur then.

Increasing the timeout value is definitely an option, but it feels like a very dirty solution - it feels like pushing the problem away rather than solving it.

Implementing a WS transaction flow on the server seems impossible - I don't have access to `TransactionScope` class when designing WinRT apps.

WS Atomic seems like overkill as well (it also requires a lot more set up, and I'm willing to bet the limited capabilities of WinRT applications will prove a big hassle to overcome).

So far my only idea (albeit one with a lot more moving parts, which sort of feels like reinventing the wheel) is to create two service methods - one which begins some long-running operation and returns some kind of "task ID", then runs the operation in the background, and saves the result of the operation (be it error or success) into a DB / storage with that task ID. The client can then poll for the operations result using that task ID via the second service method every once in a while until such a result is available (be it a success or an error).

This approach also has it's drawbacks:

- long operations become even longer, as the client needs to poll for the results
- lots of new moving parts, potentially making the whole thing less stable

What else could I possibly try to solve this issue?

PS. The actual service side is also not without limitations - it's an MS DAX service, which likely comes with it's own set of potential pitfalls and traps.

EDIT:
It appears my question has some similarity to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295498/wcf-basichttpbinding-rollback-when-reply-to-client-fails)... however, given the WinRT nature of the client and the MS DAX nature of the service I'm not sure anything in the answer is really useful to me.

Comment: Maybe you can go 4 a callback to the client if the op. has finished. Take a look at "Duplex"-Binding! ...but be aware of its limitations

Comment: @Cadburry I've implemented a Duplex binding once via WCF / SL when working on a personal project. First, it's not easy (unless there are some ready-made packages available these days) and I'm sure the restrictive set of WinRT classes might very well prove to be an impassable barrier... not to mention the potential problems on the server side (due to the MS DAX nature of the services).

Comment: Implementig is not really hard but DPB is a MS propper thing.. So 3rd party clients may unable to use that. Im not aware of the DAX limits so you just have to giv em a try ;) ..i think it will work